# timer and datagrid flash as2

Tags: flash, datagrid, timer, actionscript-2

i have a problem with autorefresh datagrid on flash CS3 actionscript 2..

the datagrid provied data from a sql database..
here is the idea, i want to set a timer function to refresh the datagrid only, so if there's any data change from the database, the grid will automatically update its data..
so as long as the timer still going, i want always check the database data if there are any change or not..

any idea where should i put the timer?
i'have tried much dummy way, but it wont give result that what i want..

or maybe some of you have any better idea about autorefreshing datagrid without push any button to run some refresh function..

share me your knowledges.. thx..

Answer (score 0):

Below are some approaches to handle this task.follow along

example:

```
      var mytimers = true;
      function load_my_msql data (){
      // write your loader here 
      //and your complete function here, then add your timer change booleon.
      //and what else you need
      }

      //you can use an enter frame function with a True/Faslse
      onEnerFrame(){
      if(mytimers){ // check that booleon
      //start function()
      }

      or 
      setTimeout(myfunction,2000) // every 2 seconds that function will reload
```

The above are the principle examples, you haven't shown any code in your question  so you will need to write your own logic.